# Slepian's Lemma for Range?

Tags: pr.probability, gaussian

Let $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ be zero mean $n$-variate Gaussian variables with covariances $\Sigma^x, \Sigma^y$. Suppose they have identical marginals ($\sigma_{i,i}^x = \sigma_{i,i}^y$ for all $i$), and otherwise $\sigma_{i,j}^x \le \sigma_{i,j}^y$. Let $R$ be the range function defined as
$$
R\left(\vec{x}\right) = \max_i x_i - \min_i x_i.
$$
Is there something like Slepian's Lemma which would imply that
$$
\mathcal{P}\left(R(\vec{x}) \ge t\right) \ge
\mathcal{P}\left(R(\vec{y}) \ge t\right)?
$$

(I tried to use a result from Muller 2001 by showing that the exceedance indicator function is 'submodular', but it turns out not to be the case. The range function is submodular, and so the inequality holds for the expected range, I think.)

**edit:** I had the inequality the wrong way, h/t @mike.

Comment: Is your inequality in the wrong direction ?  The less correlated should have bigger span.  Consider the case when $\sigma_{ii} = 1, \sigma_{ij}^y = 1, \sigma_{ij}^x = 0$.  Then R(x) in the span of  n gaussians and R(y) is actually 0.

Comment: @mike : yes, of course, I was too clever by a half, putting it in terms of exceedance instead of the CDF.